# Universal Analytics misses some goals

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

I have Universal Analytics code on my site.

I have set a goal which is a checkout confirm page by setting:

**url starts with '/index.php?route=checkout/confirm'.**

But I was surprised that UA often misses 30-40% of this goal completion.

Could you say please, why it occurs and how to set the goal correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you find out about the mismatch? Difference between Universal Analytics and server logs? Maybe some users have a blocking software (like Ghostery) installed to block Universal Analytics.

Comment: Well, I see how many checkouts I see the that UA misses some of them. Doubtfully that they have this blocking service. 
Moreover, the russian service Yandex.Metrika catches all the goals :/

Comment: I don't know where the visitors of your website live, but I assume more people are blocking Google Analytics than Yandex

Comment: Awful.
So how Im suposed to collect the data? :'(

Comment: Google Analytics is not about getting exact numbers. It's about getting trends and ratios.

Comment: But how we should define the quantity of checkouts from, for example, Google Adwords. I miss the data and calculate the wrong conversion!

Comment: Integrate Adwords into Analytics and you will get the right conversions.

Comment: Sure. I see the origin but analytics miss the goal so I don't know whether this user makes a checkout or not.